# PhoneGap with WIndows Phone Access Origin?

Tags: xml, ajax, windows-phone-7, cordova

I'm using Phonegap to build an application for multiple platforms, one of which is windows phone.

I had a similar problem with other platforms with having Ajax grab content from an XML file on the web.

I was able to solve it by adding ...

```
<access origin="*" />
```

to the config.xml file.

After that it worked on BlackBerry, Android, and IOS.

But on the windows phone emulator it doesn't fetch the data.

---

According to this page http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html Windows phone doesn't even need the Access tag and all domains should be accessible by default.

Answer (score -1):

what you might want to try is adding the 'subdomains' tag like so:

```
<access subdomains="true" origin="http://phonegap.com"/>
```

if you application needs to fetch data from more than one domain

Comment: Tried using specific domain rather then * and adding subdomain(though I'm not using one), didn't help.

Comment: so this deserves a downvote cause it didnt solve your problem?

Comment: 1. I wasn't the one who down voted. 
2. If the answer hasn't been tested on Windows 8 Phone I can see why someone would down vote it.